# Grub error 21 on windows machine?

Tags: windows, boot, grub

So for some reason my computer freezes and on restart i get this error (grub loading stage 1.5 grub, loading please wait, error 21) and can't resume to windows. Only way to be able to boot to windows is by a hard reboot.

I never had ubunto on my machine and i have searched google for what so ever information i can find but with no luck...

Edit: im on windows 7 and i tried with a new fresh install without luck.. this has been going for over a year now. but it happens so rarely that i haven't cared for it, but now im finally tired of this s**t.

Answer (score 0):

> **GRUB Error 21 Definition**: The boot loader fails when installing Ubuntu from Windows operation system
>
> You might encounter Error 21 when you tried to install Ubuntu from Windows or boot Windows after installing Ubunto and the following message appeared:
>
> GRUB loading Stage 1.5
>      Grub loading, please wait....
>      Error 21.
>
> This error may occur because ***you are trying to boot into windows without the external/original drive attached***. System optimization might resolve this problem. Try this tool to optimize your system settings and prevents systems conflicts.

Source: http://error21.org/ — this might be an explanation for your **error 21**.

Comment: thanks for that information!
Think it might be one of the following problems.

Software issue - The runtime Error 21 can be caused by a game, software, or a new plug-ins or add-ons that are associated with the program that is generating runtime Error 21, or any runtime Error.

Memory related issue - damaged memory sticks, damaged memory blocks, and space allocation issue can cause this error as well.

If im not wrong i think it all started when i got my new mobo+cpu+ram. Im going to buy some new ram today or tomorrow. I will report back if it's working or not.